# Reverse engineering JavaScript from third party website

Tags: javascript, jquery, reverse-engineering

I am looking for a tool, extension or other utility that would help me reverse engineer a JavaScript/jQuery sequence of event on a third party website. I am trying to achieve something similar on my website, and I want to understand how this was made in the first place, to be able to understand the sequence itself.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by reverse engineer? De-obfuscate?

Comment: If it is not obfuscated, then the best tool for this is likely your very own brain.

Comment: There are not all that much ways to obfuscate javascript. But we need a link to know which one was used in your specific case.

Comment: I meant seeing the course of action of a specific script (based on a scrolling event in this case). I would definitely share the link, but it is behind closed walls... So that wouldn't help.That's I kept my question kind of open-ended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the debugging function of the developer tools. E.g. Firebug. You set the breaking point at the lines you are interested in and then you can step through the Javascript code.

Comment: Wow, wasn't using breaking points at all (Chrome Dev Tools). Thanks, that'll help!

Answer (score 1):

If by reverse engineer you mean "see how it works".  The best option would be to use Firebug directly against the site in question.